# How to get a stored Dictionary<string,int> from the viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, viewstate

I am trying to get a Dictionary from a view state. But I get an error saying it is not marked as serialize.

```
var groupByCountDictionary = from supplier in supplierDirectoryList
                             group supplier by supplier.ProductCategory into grp
                             select new
                             {
                                 groupName = grp.Key,
                                 count = grp.Select(x => x.ProductCategory).Count()
                             };
ViewState["GroupbyCount"] = groupByCountDictionary;       
Dictionary<string,int> groupByDictionary = (Dictionary<string,int>) ViewState["GroupbyCount"];
```

Then at a another method after post back I am trying to get the dictionary from the view state as above which results an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, groupByCountDictionary  is not a dictionary, it is a `IEnumerable<anonymous_type>`. You can rewrite your LINQ code to use `.ToDictionary(...)` method that will return the object you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the Error occurs when I get the Dictionary from the view state. Not at the Storing phase.

Comment: @Kanishka, that is because you can't cast `IEnumerable<anonymous_type>` to `Dictionary<string,int>`